# Failed to create a cluster with command kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes

I am tring to install kubenetes on debian 9.3, I followed the instructions on this document https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/, it failed to create the cluster with timeout error, the commands I used are as follows:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.56.1:1080  # this is my internet proxy
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.56.1:1080
export NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,192.168.56.*,10.244.*,10.96.*
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.101 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

the last command hangs up for 1hour and failed with timeout, I found that several container had been running by command docker ps, the running containers included kube-controller-manager-amd64,etcd-amd64,kube-apiserver-amd64,kube-scheduler-amd64,4 instances of pause-amd64.

the error messages are as follows

```
duler-debvm01_kube-system(660259102d57385a8043d025ac189c87)": Get https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-scheduler-debvm01: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Apr 06 21:44:49 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 21:44:49.923017   10665 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Ddebvm01&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Apr 06 21:44:49 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 21:44:49.924966   10665 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.56.101:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Apr 06 21:44:49 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 21:44:49.925892   10665 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get xxx/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Ddebvm01&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Apr 06 21:44:50 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 21:44:50.029333   10665 eviction_manager.go:238] eviction manager: unexpected err: failed to get node info: node "debvm01" not found
Apr 06 21:44:50 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 21:44:50.379543   10665 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "debvm01" with API server: Post xxx: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Apr 06 21:44:52 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 21:44:52.575452   10665 event.go:209] Unable to write event: 'Post xxxx: net/http: TLS handshake timeout' (may retry after sleeping)
Apr 06 21:44:57 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: I0406 21:44:57.380498   10665 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
Apr 06 21:44:57 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: I0406 21:44:57.430059   10665 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node debvm01
Apr 06 21:45:00 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 21:45:00.030635   10665 eviction_manager.go:238] eviction manager: unexpected err: failed to get node info: node "debvm01" not found
Apr 06 21:45:01 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: I0406 21:45:01.484580   10665 kubelet_node_status.go:85] Successfully registered node debvm01
```

the above error messages has been processed and eliminated a lot of repeated lines as follows:

```
Apr 06 22:46:20 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: E0406 22:46:20.773690   10665 kubelet.go:2104] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Apr 06 22:46:25 DebVM01 kubelet[10665]: W0406 22:46:25.779141   10665 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
```

Kubernetes v1.9.3

could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

> kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.101
>   --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

From [kubeadm documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/):

> **--apiserver-advertise-address *ip-address***    The IP address the API Server will advertise it's listening on.  Specify '0.0.0.0' to use the
>   *address of the default network interface*.
>
> Unless otherwise specified, kubeadm uses the default gateway’s network
>   interface to advertise the master’s IP. If you want to use a different
>   *network interface*, specify **--apiserver-advertise-address=*ip-address***

From kubernetes [api-server documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kube-apiserver/):

> **--advertise-address *ip-address***      The IP address on which to advertise the apiserver to members of the cluster.  This address must
>   be reachable by the rest of the cluster.  If blank, the --bind-address
>   will be used.  If --bind-address is unspecified, the host's *default
>   interface* will be used.

I've done a couple of experiments which confirm that it is necessary for `ip-address` to be configured (or added as a secondary IP) to one of the master's instance interfaces. 
Just double check if that interface is up.

The last error message,

> network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

means that kubernetes networking subsystem is absent or broken. Try to install/reinstall it with

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml
```

This part described in section "(3/4) Installing a pod network" in the [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) you've mentioned.

If you are stuck, try to reinstall your cluster following [this](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/how-install-kubernetes-kubeadm/) manual.

Comment: I have checked the interface, it is up and working, I login the host by this IP address.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try.